# Why can't I create a Wi-Fi hotspot with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless, adhoc

I was able to create a wi-fi hotspot using connectify in windows but once I switched to Ubuntu I am no longer able to do the same. My Dell studio xps 1640 that runs Ubuntu asks me the password of the hotspot I just created using the System Setting -> Networking -> wireless -> create hotspot.

```
lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.

*-network               

   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 0c:60:76:6f:7f:71
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.0.0-30-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:f8000000-f8003fff

*-network

   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 00:26:b9:11:50:db
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.119 duplex=full firmware=sb v2.17 ip=83.172.121.99 latency=0 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:48 memory:fc000000-fc00ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

The above is the configurations of my network cards. that is the result that I got when i typed the following command `lshw -c network`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `lshw` output says that the  `brcmsmac` driver is being used.

[AP support is one of the TO-DO features for this driver](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211), so this probably means that, unless some other driver (from Broadcom?) offers the AP feature under Linux, you likely can't create APs under Linux with your card.